# Refreshing using VBA takes an extremely long time compared to Refresh All; is there a way to fix this?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, powerpivot

I have a number of reports that are designed to refresh themselves on open using some VBA. For my purposes, I cannot use the "refresh on open" property of connections.

For one specific report, when the VBA ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll & PivotCaches.Refresh are used to refresh the report, it takes upwards of 45 minutes to complete. If I refresh the data myself using Refresh All, it takes less than 2 minutes.

I have several other reports that employ this exact same script without seeing this massive difference in run times. The only difference I can discern between this problem report and the rest is that the others use tables with embedded SQL to create pivots, where this one loads its SQL connection to the Data Module and uses PowerPivot. Same database used, connection properties, etc.

Loaded data of problem report is ~1.7m rows. Total size of data is less than many other reports. There are about a dozen pivot tables to refresh, less than other reports without issue. Single SQL connection to pull in data. Background refresh is disabled for connections in all reports.

Relevant bit of code used in all the auto-refresh reports:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Step 0: prepare
Dim pc As PivotCache
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next

'Step 2: Refresh all data
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Step 3: refresh pivot tables to reflect new data
For Each pc In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
    pc.Refresh
Next pc

'Step 5: clean up
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Any ideas on why the VBA command is taking so much longer to refresh the data, and how I might fix it?

Comment: Why are you using RefreshAll and then refreshing each pivot table cache?  From what I understand RefreshAll in VBA is the same as doing Refresh All manually.

Comment: `.RefreshAll` will refresh the pivot tables automatically. You're doubling up when you refresh them again afterwards. That would be why it seems slower when you run your code instead of pressing the button.